# Distributed file system for android

Tags: android, dropbox, fuse, distributed-filesystem

I'm trying to develop a serverless distributed file system for android OS(a feature like Dropbox but serverless). I'm looking for suggestions on how I approach it.
I have seen about FUSE on android but didn't get a clear picture on how it would help my cause.
I saw an existing system called mobiDFS but didn't get any information about it.
Please provide me some tutorials,papers or existing solutions to get me started.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Chords algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29) may be a good hint. It explains how to keep a "ring with fingers" of connected devices so that each device holds its own part of data that any other device can retrieve when each device only knows about a few others (not about all).

The algorithm addresses the goals to support registering and unregistering of devices, and has ways of recovering from unexpected loss of device that has failed to unregister from the ring properly. Seems exactly that you need.

As I understand, in your system devices will talk with each other directly. Probably this is possible, some goods advice on technical solutions would also be interesting for me (so +1 on this question). At the initial stages for the proof of concept, probably some wireless router without any software stack (just as router) can be used.